# Show $c||x|| \leq ||Ax|| \leq d||x||$ where $c$ and $d$ are positive constants

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space  and $A:X \to X$ a continuous linear map which is bijective.

Show for all $x \in X$ $$c||x|| \leq ||Ax|| \leq d||x||$$ where $c$ and $d$ are positive constants.

This is the proof:

Take $X$ and $Y$ in the open mapping theorem since $A$ is bijective hence $B=A^{-1}$ exists and is continuous.

As $A$ and $B$ are linear maps and continuity and boundedness coincide,  we have for some positive constants $c$ and $k$ and for all $x,y \in X$:

$$||Ax|| \leq d||x||$$ and $$||By|| \leq k||y||$$

We let $y=Ax$ then we get $$||x|| =||BAx|| \leq K||Ax||\leq Kd||x||$$

The proof then says let $d=K^{-1}$

But I am unsure of where to go from here?

Comment: In the last line of equalities and inequalities, you don't need the very last term. $\|x\| \le K \|Ax\|$; now put "$c$" $= 1/K$. (Note - you used the letter "c" earlier, change THAT occurrence to $d$ to match the requirement in your problem exactly.)

Comment: It seems you reversed the roles of $c,d$ at some point.  That is, you wrote $c||x|| \le ||Ax||$ in the title and at the beginning of your Question, then switched to $||Ax|| \le c||x||$.  Something similar affects your use of $d $.